# generate random numbers within a range with a percentage of them a specific value

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, graph-algorithm

I need to create large (see more on this below) random graphs to compare performance of Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford, and Floyd's algorithms on shortest path graph traversal. I'm storing the adjacencies in an array. So far, I generated random weights between vertices, and filled the main diagonal with 0's. I also have symmetry about the main diagonal (I'm assuming the graphs are undirected but not necessarily completely connected).

The random values are in the range 0 - 24 ish, generated using `rand() % 25`. The problem is that I'd like the graphs to be sparser (i.e. have less edges). Is there a way to generate random numbers within a range and have about 1/3 to 1/2 of the generated numbers be a specific value? Note that the random distribution isn't very important for what I'm doing...

Another question: how large of a graph should I test to see performance differences? 10 vertices? 100? 1000? 10000000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ offers the `discrete_distribution` and `uniform_int_distribution` classes that together achieve what you want. An example follows:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

template<typename rgen>
int custom_random_int(rgen& mt) {
    // Returns 0 at a 1/3 chance, 1 at a 2/3 chance
    std::discrete_distribution<> d({1, 2});
    // Uniform distribution of integers in [0, 24]
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> ud(0, 24);
    if (d(mt) == 0) {
      // Return 0 at 1/3 chance
      return 0;
    } else {
      // Output a random number at 2/3 chance
      return ud(mt);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Fixed seed of 1 for demonstration purposes
    std::seed_seq ss{ 1 };
    std::mt19937 mt(ss);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           std::cout << custom_random_int(mt) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I implement a function that returns that distribution? I would declare everything above the `for` loop in main or a driver program, and pass the objects into the function?

Comment: In a way, yes you would.